# Stop WordPress Visual Editor converting backticks into code blocks

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor, wysiwyg

I need my frontend wp_editor() to not convert backticks into code automatically. I have checked the settings config in the `tiny_mce_before_init` filter as well as the documentation on the TinyMCE website and just can't find it. Current default behaviour means text wrapped inside backticks (``) is converted into a `<code></code>` block automatically and I don't want that.

Comment: Line 82 - 84 of wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wptextpattern/plugin.js Is what causes this to happen, does anyone know of a way to disable it without modifying core WP Code? You can comment this out and it will stop but I want a more fault-tolerant way of doing it so that updating core doesn't wipe your change out.

Comment: Why not just use the HTML entity for the backtick `&#96;`?

Comment: Thanks mate you've actually pointed me in the right direction. I know what I'm looking for now. Seems we can remove the inline action or disable that plugin entirely so it doesn't change any content on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

This has solved the problem, simply remove the plugin which automatically formats text as you type, from loading in the first place.

```
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'rwebster_editor_remove_wptextpattern', 1, 99 );
function rwebster_editor_remove_wptextpattern( $plugins ) {
    $wptextpattern = array_search( 'wptextpattern', $plugins );
    unset( $plugins[$wptextpattern] );
    return $plugins;
}
```

Comment: You should be aware that the plugin probably does more than just that (I also find it annoying that someone above decided what certain things mean with zero configuration options, at least right now)

Comment: It's purely for changing formatting as you type. Code backticks, headings, lists. You can add extra ones to it as well. For completeness I'll probably update my answer to include removing specific things as well. All documented here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wptextpattern/plugin.js

Comment: exactly, "purely changing the format", while might be something you do not need, might also be something that other people depend on in their writing flow, so this solution is good for people that do not depend on those goodies, but will be more problematic for those that do

Comment: Yep I'll make some nice edits later, running on 4 hours #Naptime

Comment: another comment, reading the question more carefully, is that if you need this only for front end editor, you should add the filter only when it is going to be displayed, and not "globally"

Comment: I'm having difficulty creating it so it only removes the code formatting. The way it works is you have to rebuild the whole list of settings, but I'm not able to successfully reproduce the space patterns to get them to work. I can add an empty inline one (great), include the enter settings, but not the space. So UL/OL isn't working.